# url rewrite not working after changing site url

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, permalinks

Because we want to launch the website, I had to change the site url from **devdom.com to livedom.com**, the **start page loads** fine, but I **can't load other pages, unless I deactivate pretty url/permalink settings!** It used to work fine, before I changed the site url. If I use any permalink setting, the server will throw me a 404 not found message.

What I did:

- changing the `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` property in wp-config.php
- changing the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` using the wp-config.php (I checked it at the db, the values were updated properly)
- running the db search replace script (see https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) which worked fine

the content of my .htaccess is:

```
# WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# Media Library
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
# Disallow access to important files
<FilesMatch "(^\.|wp-config\.php|xmlrpc\.php|(?<!robots)\.txt|(liesmich|readme)\.*)">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
# Prevent Directory Listings
Options -Indexes
```

I'm using apache on an ubuntu server, the wordpress version is 4.0.

Hope sb of you guys can help me, would appreciated it.

Thank you,

Ronin

********** UPDATE **********

- I'm not sure if it matters, but it's a **network/multisite** installation.
- also, I set the `ServerName` Directive to **www.livedom.com** on the vshost file /etc/apache2/sites-available/www.devdom.com.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I made it! On the same box there are various other pages, due using vhosts it's possible to run all of those pages.

Now, that's what I came up with:

- copied the old vhost config file to a new one: `cp devdom.com.conf livedom.com.conf`
- registered the new vhost: `a2ensite livedom.com.conf`
- unregistred the old vhost, removed the old vhost config file: `a2dissite devdom.com.conf` `rm devdom.com.conf`
- restarted the rewrite module: `a2dismod rewrite` `a2enmod rewrite`

after each step I restarted the apache service: `service apache2 restart`

that did the trick for me :)